# NPE when referencing a toString

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

```
Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Deck.toString(Deck.java:83)
at DeckDriver.main(DeckDriver.java:25)
```

I'm completely lost as to why i'm getting this error message. The `d.toString` is supposed to display 52 lines of code describing the Deck d.

Deck class

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Deck
{
    private Card[] deck;
    private int nextCard;
    Face face;
    Suit suit;


    /**
     * Default Constructor        
     *
     * <hr>
     * Date created: Feb 17, 2014 
     *
     * 
     */
    public Deck()
    {
        nextCard = 0;
        deck = new Card[52];
        int iCount;
        for(iCount=0; iCount<52; iCount++)
        {
            Card c = new Card(iCount);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Copy Constructor        
     *
     * <hr>
     * Date created: Feb 17, 2014 
     *
     * 
     * @param existingDeck
     */
    public Deck(Deck existingDeck)
    {
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<52;i++)
        {
            this.deck[i] = existingDeck.deck[i];
        }
    }

    /**
     * toString         
     *
     * <hr>
     * Date created: Feb 17, 2014 
     *
     * <hr>
     * @return
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    public String toString()
    {
        int iCount = 0;
        String description = "";
        for(iCount=0; iCount<52;iCount++)
        {
            description += deck[iCount].toString();
        }
        return description;
    }

    /**
     * Shuffles the deck       
     *
     * <hr>
     * Date created: Feb 17, 2014
     *
     * <hr>
     */
    public void shuffle()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        nextCard = 0;
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<52;i++)
        {
            int x = r.nextInt(52);
            Card c = new Card();
            c=deck[x];
            deck[x]=deck[i];
            deck[i]=c;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Deals individual card.        
     *
     * <hr>
     * Date created: Feb 17, 2014
     *
     * <hr>
     * @return
     */
    public Card dealACard()
    {
        Card c;
        c=deck[nextCard];
        nextCard++;

        return c;
    }

    public String dealAHand(int handSize)
    {
        int i;
        String hand="";
        for(i=0;i==handSize;i++)
        {
            hand+="" + dealACard();
        }
        return hand;
    }
}
```

DeckDriver class

```
public class DeckDriver
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Deck d = new Deck();
        System.out.print(d.toString()); //(this is the DeckDriver.main(DeckDriver.java:25))
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll add my entire deck class.

Comment: By your current code, all the elements in your array are `null`...

Comment: What is the contents of line 83 in your Deck class ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no object added to array in default constructor. You should initialize every field of the array the same way as you do in the other constructor.

Answer (score 1):

These lines

```
for(iCount=0; iCount<52; iCount++)
{
    Card c = new Card(iCount);
}
```

don't have much effect.  You're not storing the new `Card` object anywhere, so it will get thrown away by the garbage collection process.  They should probably say something line this.

```
for(iCount=0; iCount<52; iCount++)
{
    deck[iCount] = new Card(iCount);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to prevent against NPE is to use Apache Commons Lang StringUtils.

In this case, it looks like StringUtils.defaultString(deck[iCount]) would be the way to go.
If it's null, defaultString will return "" (an empty string).

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#defaultString%28java.lang.String%29

If you decide to not use StringUtils, the best practice is to always check for null before doing .toString().

Answer (score 0):

You're initializing your array correctly, but not *assigning* new `Card`s to it in your constructor:

```
public Deck()
{
    nextCard = 0;
    deck = new Card[52];
    int iCount;
    for(iCount=0; iCount<52; iCount++)
    {
        Card c = new Card(iCount);
    }
}
```

You instantiate each card ... then throw it away. This means every element in your `deck` array is `null` as that is the default value.